# How to remove an element from a dictionary in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{"key": [{"sub-key1": "value1", "sub-key2": "value2"},{"sub-key1": "value3", "sub-key3": "value4"}]}
```

How do I pop sub-key1 from above dictionary?

I was able to pop the sub-key1 through for loop and dataframes, however like to know if there is more efficient way to do it?

Comment: **Which** `sub-key1`?

Comment: Please post the code you wrote to do this for comparison with the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {
"key": [
    {"sub-key1": "value1", "sub-key2": "value2"},
    {"sub-key1": "value3", "sub-key3": "value4"}
]}

key_to_remove = "sub-key1"
data["key"] = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != key_to_remove} for d in data["key"]]
```

In this example, the list comprehension iterates through each dictionary in the list under the "key" key. It creates a new dictionary for each one, excluding the "sub-key1" key. Finally, the updated list of dictionaries is assigned back to the "key" key in the original dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any example of use I think this answer will be appropriate. In my opinion, list comprehension will be the best method.

```
data["key"] = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != "sub-key1"} for d in data["key"]]  # data == dictionary which you provided
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 instances of "sub-key1" in your code block, each with a different value. Assuming you are just looking to pull either 1 or all instances of a known key out of your data set, I think I can provide some helpful information.

For readability, I will add some variables to your example:

```
data1 = {"sub-key1": "value1", "sub-key1": "value2"}
data2 = {"sub-key1": "value3", "sub-key3": "value4"}
dataset = [data1, data2]
generations = {"key": dataset}
```

If we assume you know the key of the data you're looking for, and you want to pop the first instance of it:

```
data = generations["key"]
value = [d for d in data if "sub-key1" in d][0].pop("sub-key1")
```

The above will index all your data containing "sub-key1" and pop it's first instance. If you are instead looking to pop all instances, it's even easier:

```
data = generations["key"]
values = [d.pop("sub-key1") for d in data if "sub-key1" in d]
```

This will instead pop all instances of "sub-key1" from your data. Of course, this assumes you know the key of the generation or whatever. If instead you want all generations, there's also this:

```
data = [generations[l][i] for l in generations for i in range(len(generations[l]))]
values = [d.pop("sub-key1") for d in data if "sub-key1" in d]
```

This is kind of the same thing as above, except it gets a list of each dataset in generations (assuming there are more than 1) and stores each dictionary in each dataset, then pops those dictionaries just like before.

If this does not fit the desired use case, I will update with a better answer once there is more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dict comprehension:

```
res = {k:[{a:b for a,b in i.items() if a!='sub-key1'} for i in v] for k,v in Dict.items()}
```